Why Axios throws me 406 error using @mailchimp/mailchimp_transactional?
I want to implement an endpoint to send emails in Express project using @mailchimp/mailchimp_transactional library.
I've written this:
var express = require('express')
const mailchimp = require('@mailchimp/mailchimp_transactional')(
  'API_KEY'
)
var app = express()

app.post('/', async function (req, res) {
  const response = await mailchimp.messages.send({
    message: {
      from_email: 'test@test.com',
      subject: 'Test',
      text: 'Test',
      to: [
        {
          email: 'PROVIDED_EMAIL',
          type: 'to',
        },
      ],
    },
  })
  res.json(response)
})

var server = app.listen(5000, function () {
  console.log('Express App running at http://127.0.0.1:5000/')
})


When I request to this endpoint, it throws me this:
{
  "message": "Request failed with status code 406",
  "name": "AxiosError",
}

Why this is happening? Also I've used NestJS but the result is same.
I tried implementing in front-end project and it works like a charm but I need to implement it in back-end one.
Thanks for your helps.
